# Mobile app for workflow/timesheets + GIS Asset collection required

Tags: software-recommendations, mobile, workflow

We're looking for a solution to move our field operatives from paper based input to electronic field input on tablets to record workflow and map assets. Work involves land drainage (working on watercourses - reforming/reprofiling, desilting, flailmowing, improvement works etc.)

We need to make it as simple to use a possible so we want an integrated form + mapping solution. We've looked at things like ESRI collector and Survey123 but they're too basic for our needs.

Example workflow for an operative:

Start of day, gets job on tablet.

Use tablet to log start of work, vehicle start mileage etc.

Complete mandatory vehicle checks, risk assessments etc. (need to be recorded on tablet).

Does job, vehicle tracked on GIS map, throughout job operative can input asset data on to GIS.

Ends job, time recorded on tablet + additional info.

This is a very simplified example and more info will need to be captured throughout. Ultimately all the info needs to get back to head office to be verified and processed.

Big picture is that we want to move away from paper timesheets etc. as the app should be able to provide the info to generate this and asset info collected in the field will go on to the central GIS.

Unfortunately don't really have any in house capability to develop this ourselves. We do have good desktop GIS experience and knowledge. We're UK based and hoping to be able to outsource the app development. Any suggestions welcome?

Comment: There's an SE site devoted to [softwarerecs.se], but this almost reads like an informal RFP.

Comment: You can try [NextGIS Mobile](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-mobile/) + [NextGIS Web](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-web/) + [Formbuilder](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-formbuilder). Custom application also available using [NextGIS Mobile SDK](http://docs.nextgis.com/ngmobile_dev/toc.html). I'm developer from NextGIS.